# Keynote: using color in equation to match keynote color scheme

Tags: color

Since Keynote 8.x support latex equations natively, I wonder whether it is possible to assign colours to parts of an equation to match the color scheme used in the presentation. E.g., I like to highlight just parts of an equation such as

```latex
  \int_a^b {\color{red} f(x)} dx
```

I'd like to use the keynote colours to match the presentation, instead of the "plain" latex red.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! This should be easy with `xcolor`, but what are the Keynote colours?

Comment: Keynote has some standard colours that I use in the presentation. It would be nice to use the same colours in the latex formulas

Comment: In this case, see in the documentation of `xcolor`, looking at the sections on colours by names, you find more or less the same colours as you need. In addition, xcolor lets you mix colours (and give them a name if needed).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The [Keynote app](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202501) use internally [blahTeX](http://gva.noekeon.org/blahtexml/blahtexml-0.9-doc.pdf).

In section 2.4 of the *blahTeX* manual, all supported colors with the `\color` command are listed:

> GreenYellow Yellow yellow Goldenrod Dandelion Apricot Peach Melon YellowOrange Orange BurntOrange Bittersweet RedOrange Mahogany Maroon BrickRed Red red OrangeRed RubineRed WildStrawberry Salmon CarnationPink Magenta magenta VioletRed Rhodamine Mulberry RedViolet Fuchsia Lavender Thistle Orchid DarkOrchid Purple Plum Violet RoyalPurple BlueViolet Periwinkle CadetBlue CornflowerBlue MidnightBlue NavyBlue RoyalBlue Blue blue Cerulean Cyan cyan ProcessBlue SkyBlue Turquoise TealBlue Aquamarine BlueGreen Emerald JungleGreen SeaGreen Green green ForestGreen PineGreen LimeGreen YellowGreen SpringGreen OliveGreen RawSienna Sepia Brown Tan Gray Black black White white

The manual also say that there is no support for color models, so you cannot use `\color[rgb]{0.2,0.3,0.4}` for example.

**But**, as highlighted by *Nuno* in the comments, the Keynote manual shows an exemple of use with HEX color code. So you can use `\color{RRGGBB}`, where RR, GG, and BB are hex values between `00` and `FF` for the **r**ed, the **g**reen and the **b**lue component. E.g. `\color{0A7C10}`.

As you are using a Mac, if you have installed MacTeX, in the Applications folder, there is a folder `TeX` who contains the app [**LaTeXit**](https://pierre.chachatelier.fr/latexit/latexit-home.php?lang=en), and from it, you can create transparency PNG or PDF of formulas with all features from LaTeX (with the packages you need), and adding it to the Keynote document. This app allow you to reopen the equation from Keynote.app to modify it, so you don't have frozen formulas in you document.

Comment: This is very helpful information. Thank you.

Comment: As (briefly) exemplified in the [Keynote documentation](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202501), you can also include HEX colour codes (e.g. `#FFA500`) instead of colour names (e.g. `blue`), such as `2 + \color{FFA500}a`

Answer (score 15):

I created the following list of blahtex colors which I am finding useful to pick colors for latex equations.

[image]

Comment: ...but does it answer the question? Not at the moment.

Comment: What is the concern?

Comment: This is a Q&A site. Answers should answer the question... general advice that might be tangential to a question is better-suited in a comment. Your question is whether it's possible to assign colours to parts of an equation. This answer gives provides a list of (blahtex) colours you can pick from, so doesn't answer the question.

Comment: It is useful information that is relevant to anybody who is looking at this. What a nice way to put people off...

Comment: Don't take it personally. This style of post just doesn't fit the site model.

Comment: This is an extremely useful supplement to the accepted answer.  Knowing `\color` is not useful in of itself without knowing what colors one can use and how they look.